# Converting an equation

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm

I have a equation in the form of string like this `1+(x*10) = 21` . I have to covert it like this `x = (21-1)/10` in any language . I do not want an exact solution but Please give me some hint .

Comment: So.... `var x = ( 21 - 1 ) / 10;` ?

Comment: @Ben Yes like this

Comment: Well... glad I could help then I guess.

Comment: "convert" means solve to the form "x = ..." and return the result as string?

Comment: @Benjamin Yes U r correct

Comment: that will take some advanced text parsing. you have to consider all the different operands and parenthesis. maybe use polish notation to build the call (reminds me of school)

Comment: check this out https://technologyconversations.com/2014/03/28/java-8-tutorial-through-katas-reverse-polish-notation-medium/

Comment: Out of curiousity, are you asking this question in relation to an assignment you have? If yes let us know so we can label the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If a hint is enough for you check out this library:

http://algebra.js.org/

It is capable of taking definitions of equations (as string or step by step), solve them and make the result available as string.

Comment: I do not have to use any library

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way - call some CAS (computer algebra system) program from command line passing equation to solve. Like:

```
maxima --very-quiet -r 'solve ([1+(x*10) = 21], [x]);'
```

And get results back from standart output. But of course this should be done server-side, 
i.e. if from PHP - can be executed with `shell_exec()` function.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this problem can be divided into 2 stages, finding x's side (left or right of the "="), and scanning and converting a literal along with the appropriate operation.

For the first stage, you can find which part of the equation x lies in by simply comparing the indexes of "=" and "x" in the String.

There are 2 types of components you need to worry about now i.e. operands (values) and operations (+, - etc) .
You can try shifting operands from the "x-side" to the other, by simply converting the operation associated with the value (+ becomes - and vice versa, same for * and /). For example, 1 + x = 7. 1 is the operand and '+' is the operation associated with 1, which gets converted to '-' when it moves to the other side.

Do make sure to add a bracket at the start and end of the right hand side every time you move an operand and operation to the other side, so that the equation maintains the order of calculations needed to be done.

Hope this helps!